# activeadmin: nested resources belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I need to make nested resources in activeadmin like

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/companies/1/admin_documents
```

I tried

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminDocument do

  belongs_to :company

end
```

But there is no result, I get an error `No route matches [GET] "/admin/companies/1/admin_documents"`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that I have need to do is

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminDocument do

  controller do 
    belongs_to :company, polymorphic: true 
  end

end
```

routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :companies do
    resources :admin_documents
  end
end
```